# iOS Swift Custom Cell NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have CollectionView in TableView. everything ok but. when I want to navigate my cell to another viewController I got error

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

    let bookView: BookSingleController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BookSingle") as! BookSingleController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bookView, animated: true)


    bookView.bookID = "\(self.books[indexPath.row].id)"

    print(self.books[indexPath.row].id)
}
```

Xcode show me error on self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bookView, animated: true) line. this is error description:

```
Value of 'RelatedBookTableViewCell' has no member 'navigationController'
```

RelatedBookTableViewCell is my custom cell class:

```
class RelatedBookTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Where is my problem?

thanks.

Comment: You can use a custom delegate, in order that the UICollectionView tell the UITableView which will tells its UINavigationController (trough it's UIViewController) that it needs to push a new view controller.

Comment: A cell should not act as a data source or delegate for other cells. This is a controller's job. If you do want to keep this setup, delegate the cell selection to a `UIViewController` instance. Cells simply do not have a navigation controller property.

Comment: @Larme I use UINavigationControllerDelegate in my RelatedBookTableViewCell class but error still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below code you can get the Top viewcontroller and using that view controller you can perform your push operation

```
  let objViewController = UIApplication.topViewController()!
```

Use this extension

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will either need to:

1. Use a delegate pattern like some have suggested.

Where you pass the call from the collectionView delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to your own custom delegate/protocol on the cell that the UITableViewController which displays the cell is a delegate to. This can be set in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

swift

**Custom Protocol**

`protocol DisplayBookDelegate {
    func displayBook(bookId: String)
}`

**In the tableViewController**

```
class tableViewController: UITableViewController, DisplayBookDelegate {

    ...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.delegate = self
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func displayBook(let bookId) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bookView, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**In the cell**

```
var delegate: DisplayBookDelegate?

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.delegate.displayBook("1")
}
```

1. Use notifications and pass the `bookId` in a dictionary on the notification object

**objc**: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:"kDisplayBookView" object:@{"bookId":"1"}];`

**swift** `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kDisplayBookView", object: ["bookId":"1"])`

Answer (score -1):

Try pushing the VC from the root controller in your application.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

Comment: thanks dear Edder Núñez, can you please explain more?

Comment: When you nest UIViews it's hard to keep track of the navigation controller. But you can access to root from the application itself from anywhere in your code since it's a Singleton. In there you can push VCs.